# SwiftUI : How can I set limit of drag gesture range in 'onChange'

Tags: swiftui, swipe

```
import SwiftUI

struct TaskRowView: View {

    @State private var offsets : CGSize = .zero
    @State private var isSwipped : Bool = false
    @State private var isShowCreateTimerView : Bool = false
    @EnvironmentObject var vm : CalendarViewModel
    var task : TaskModel
    var isShowActionSheet : Bool = false
  
  var body: some View {
      ZStack {
          Color.red
          HStack {
              Spacer()
              Button(action: {
                  
              }, label: {
                  Image(systemName: "pencil")
                      .foregroundColor(.white)
                      .font(.title)
                      .frame(width : 80, height : 100)
                      .background(.green)
              })
              
              Button(action: {
                  vm.deleteTask(task: task)
              }, label: {
                  Image(systemName: "trash")
                      .foregroundColor(.white)
                      .font(.title)
                      .frame(width : 60, height : 100)
              })
          }
          
          HStack {
            VStack(alignment : .leading) {
                Text(task.title)
                .font(.title2.bold())
                
                Text("Scheduled time : \(task.remindedTime)mim")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.bottom, 6)
            }
            .padding(.leading, 35)
            
            Spacer()
            }//hst
            .frame(maxWidth : .infinity)
            .frame(height : 100)
            .background(Color.init(uiColor: .systemYellow))
            .overlay(
              Rectangle()
                  .fill(task.selectedColor)
                  .frame(width : 25)
                  .cornerRadius(8, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft])
              ,alignment: .leading
            )
            .cornerRadius(10, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft])
            .offset(x : offsets.width)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged({ gesture in
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                            if gesture.translation.width < 0 {
                                if isSwipped {
                                    offsets.width = gesture.translation.width - 140
                                } else {
                                    offsets.width = gesture.translation.width
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .onEnded({ gesture in
                        withAnimation {
                            if gesture.translation.width < 0 {
                                if gesture.translation.width < -60 {
                                    isSwipped = true
                                    offsets.width = -140
                                } else {
                                    isSwipped = false
                                    offsets.width = 0
                                }
                            } else {
                                isSwipped = false
                                offsets.width = 0
                            }
                        }
                    })
            )
        }
      .cornerRadius(10, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft])
      .padding(.leading, 20)
    }
}
```

This is my Code, and attached file is my simulator view.
[image]

What I want to do is to restrict the onChange range to cover the offset of view.
I control my swipeAction with View offsets, however I want to give drag width in onchange function for 200.

I can make my view perfect, If I can control gesture value to only -200.

I don't know how I can handle it.
Thanks!